# assigning attribute to a method

Tags: python, scipy

I have a class for a dynamical system, with methods for the ODE function and also the event function to terminate integration. I want to solve this with `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`. According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html?highlight=s), this is done by assigning an attribute to your event function, as `myEvent.terminal = True`. However, since I have all my functions in an object, these are methods and not objects themselves, so I can't assign attributes. Any suggestions?

M(not)WE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

class MySystem:

    def __init__(self):
        self.param_ = 1

    def dynamics(self,t,x):
        return (x-self.param)**3-x

    def event(self, t, x):
        return x

model = MySystem()
event1 = model.event
event1.terminal = True # this does not work
sol = solve_ivp(model.dynamics, [0, 100], [0, 10], events=event1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you made two instances of `MySystem`:

```
model1 = MySystem()
model2 = MySystem()
```

If `model1.event.terminal = True` were allowed, then it would also affect
`model2.event.terminal`.  Python disallows setting attributes on methods to
prevent this surprising action at a distance. 
More on why this is disallowed is [explained here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/#future-directions).

Per [PEP-0232](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) (my emphasis):

> **It is not possible to set
>   attributes on bound or unbound methods**, except by doing so explicitly on the
>   underlying function object

It is possible to set attributes on the method using `event1.__dict__['terminal'] = True`
but note that doing so affects all instances of `MySystem`, not just the one instance, `model`.

Since this affects `MySystem.event` at the class level, it is better to set `event.terminal` in the class definition,
or by using `MySystem.event.terminal = True` immediately after the class is defined. (Note that `MySystem.event` is the underlying function object
referred to in the PEP quote above.)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MySystem:

    def __init__(self):
        self.param = 1

    def dynamics(self,t,x):
        return (x-self.param)**3-x

    def event(self, t, x):
        return x
    event.terminal = True
# MySystem.event.terminal = True       # also works


model = MySystem()
event1 = model.event
# event1.__dict__['terminal'] = True   # works, but perhaps confusing because it affects all instances

sol = solve_ivp(model.dynamics, t_span=(0, 1.5), y0=[1], events=event1)
print(sol)
plt.plot(sol['t'], sol['y'][0])
plt.scatter(sol['t_events'][0], [0], c='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want to achieve. But to give you some ideas:

1.you can try to make a wrapper for the function event, or make the function receive an object that can take an input as you like.

2. you can give the input you want to the model object and internally set it to the event, or create a function that gives it to the event once set to the model object.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `self` from the `event` and add `@staticmethod` on top, this allows you to assign `terminal` to event1.

```py
    @staticmethod
    def event(t, x):
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, the scipy document is very unclear, this thread saved me. Here is how do in a bit different way. I define the event inside a member function that warps the ivp routine, where you can access the instance 'self' . Hope this will help someone.

```
def solve(self, y0, T, dy_dt):
    def ivp_event(t, y):
        E = self.get_energy(y)
        return E - self.E_stop # E_stop is the target point

    ivp_event.terminal = True        
    res = solve_ivp(
        fun=dy_dt, t_span=(0, T), y0=y0,
        events=ivp_event, **kw)

    if not res.success:
        raise Exception(res.message)
    ys = res.y.T
    return(res.t, ys, res.nfev)
```